# How do you change the artist catalogue image in Windows Media Player?

Tags: music, windows-media-player, album-art

I would like to customize my artist catalog album cover. What I mean is when you select Music/Artist, all artists of which you 2+ albums have their music appear in what is essentially a subfolder within WMP. I want to change the album covers that appear on the catalog itself. WMP seems to just select some random cover from that artist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to specify which album cover should be shown for an artist. Also, there's no such thing as 'artist art' in WMP - the only artwork that is supported is per-album.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-Click on Folder
2. Left Click Properties
3. Select Customize Tab
4. Select Choose File... under Folder pictures