# How do I change the artist image in Media Player?

Tags: windows-11, windows-media-player, media-player

I have this displayed in my Media Player.

[image: screenshot]

Obviously, my album is not by John F. Kennedy. How can I change the artist picture?

<sub>*This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/q/594677), which asks about the legacy Windows Media Player.*</sub>

Comment: The “Music” app in macOS does this as well. Unsure about Windows, but I believe it can’t be changed in macOS.

Answer (score 0):

The steps described below are from this [section](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-get-started-media-player-app-windows-11-preview#editinfo_mediaplayer:%7E:text=How%20to%20edit%20track%20and,the%20new%20information%20you%20provided.) of the article [How to get started with the Media Player app on Windows 11 (preview)](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-get-started-media-player-app-windows-11-preview):

> **How to edit track and album info on Media Player app**
>
> To edit the information of a music file or album, use these steps:
>
> 1. Open Media Player.
> 2. Click on Music library.
> 3. (Optional) Right-click the song and select the Properties option to view the current information.
> 4. Click the Close button.
>    5.Right-click the song and select the Edit info option.
>
> [image: Mini player]
> Source: Windows Central (Image credit: Source: Windows Central)
>
> 6. Make the necessary edits like song title, track number, artist, year, genre, etc.
> 7. Click the Save button.
> 8. (Optional) Click the Albums tab.
> 9. Open an album.
> 10. Click the Edit info button. Album Edit Info
>
> [image: Album Edit Info]
> Source: Windows Central (Image credit: Source: Windows Central)
>
> 11. Make the necessary editions to the album, including changing the album name, year, artist, genre, album cover, etc.Quick tip: You can
>     click the Update album info online option to fix the match using the
>     app online database. Select the album to match the songs, and click
>     the Save button. Edit album info
>
> [image]
> Source: Windows Central (Image credit: Source: Windows Central)
>
> 12. Click the Save button. After you complete the steps, the track will save with the new information you provided.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I'm trying to change the *artist image*, not the track or album info.

Comment: @sorbet The artist image us the album art which can be changed while edit the the album/song on step 11.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change the artist image as far as I know. But there's an option in settings to disable the automatic retrieval of artist and album art. When turned off, it removes all artist images and only shows album art that's stored locally.

[image]